# Google Compute Engine: Can't access running Docker container through http request

Tags: docker, flask, google-compute-engine, gunicorn, docker-proxy

So I have this running container on GCE and all requests from the outside fail to connect.

if I do `docker ps --all` i get:

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                       COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                                       NAMES
c516555621f0   hydra-parser:hydra-parser   "/bin/sh -c 'gunicor…"   11 hours ago   Up 11 hours   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp, :::8000->8000/tcp   nervous_neumann
```

And it seems that the ports are open too.

```
imarquezc@hydra-parser:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      557/sshd            
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8000            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      32722/docker-proxy  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      557/sshd            
tcp6       0      0 :::8000                 :::*                    LISTEN      32729/docker-proxy
```

Aditionally, if I curl to localhost/0.0.0.0 it works ok

```
imarquezc@hydra-parser:~$ curl localhost:8000
<h1>EUD Extractor</h1>
```

Other info:

I already have enabled http and https traffic on google's console.

Also added the      `default-allow-http, http-server, https-server` network tags

My Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

RUN apt-get -y update
RUN apt-get install poppler-utils python3 python3-pip -y


COPY requirements.txt /
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN python3
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

ADD . /

RUN python3 ./stanza_downloader.py

CMD gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 main:app
```

and I run the container using:

`docker run -p 8000:8000 hydra-parser:hydra-parser`

What I am missing? Please help!

Answer (score 0):

The tags you are using do not enable port 8000. They enable ports 80 and 443.

Create a VPC firewall ingress rule for port 8000.